# google recaptcha not working on safari

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am trying to figure out why captcha never proves true on safari, sadly I dont have apple products and am dependent on a friend to test it for me.  Before I start asking him to do more than submit forms, can anyone see an issue with this code that safari might not jive with but opera, iexplorer, firefox and chrome do??

```
if(isset($_POST['SubButton'])){     
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $privatekey = "******";
    $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $data = json_decode($response);
    if(isset($data->success) && $data->success==true){
```